# Save image (base64 / binary) to filesystem in phonegap and make it appear in the gallery

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am getting a JSon response from w web service that returns an image in either base4 or binary depending on what i want. Now what i would like to do is save this image to the filesystem in a way it appears in the gallery of that phone. In android i would like the image to appear in the gallery under a folder whose name is the same as my app .

I am aware that on camera.getPicture in phonegap there is an option to save to gallery. How do i achieve this with my scenario without using plugins.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to create folder with your app name in `'/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/'` and your images will automatically appear in your gallery.

Comment: Would you happen to have a soln for IOS

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin wich can do the job: https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

```
window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
    function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    },
    function(err){
        console.log(err);
    },
    document.getElementById('mycanvas')
);
```

Once installed you can use this function to save a canvas. I know you will have to convert the base64 to a canvas, but it worked for me.